# How to match manipulator as template parameter and enable function call for specific ones

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a requirement where I have variadic template parameters passed to a function. Of course there are going to be different implementations of the function depending on the template parameter. I need to identify manipulators as template parameters.

```
//If T is manipulator call this method
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const T& t, const Args&... args){
    /*Do something if T is manipulator*/
} 

//Otherwise this one
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const T& t, const Args&... args){
    /*Do something if T is not a manipulator type*/
}
```

I have tried using `std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(/*some specific manipulator*/), T>::value>`. But a problem with this approach is that some manipulators don't fit to this. Could someone suggests me a better solution than the mentioned. Also not all the manipulators has the same signature, and their return types are defined at compile time.

[Manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Comment: " some manipulator doesn't fit to this."  what does that mean?  Can you use is_base_of instead of is_same?

Comment: @xaxxon for e.g. setprecision have unspecified return type. So I can't compare using is_same. I am not sure about is_base_of.

Comment: Please give an actual concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @xaxxon I have provided a link to all the manipulators. Each one of them have a different syntax. If I have to identify each one of them and call respective method. What would be the efficient way?

Comment: Do you really jsut want to know if you can say cout << T?   Because you can check that directly just by checking to see if operator<< is overloaded for T

Comment: The problem at hand seems more complex than the question shows. I think your approach would be to distinguish between noarg manipulators and manipulators taking an argument

Comment: The noarg manipulators are easy to check: `std::is_same<T, std::ios_base& (std::ios_base&)`, the ones taking an argument, I'm still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to see if you can apply it to a stream, then maybe this will do what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
using int_t = int;

template<typename T, int_t<decltype(operator<<(std::declval<istream>(), declval<T>()))> = 0>
void go(T f){
    cout << f << true << false << endl;  
}

struct foo{};

int main()
{

  go(&boolalpha);
  go(foo());

}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/rDt4Gu